# How to remove duplicates from a large csv file?

Tags: database, csv, duplicates

I have few csv email database files, each with around 4-6M rows and 3 columns.

There are many duplicates but since csv can only load upto 1M I am not able to remove it.

Is there any way or any software which I can use to remove duplicate entries?

Comment: A quick google search came up with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849793/read-large-csv-file-with-many-duplicate-values-drop-duplicates-while-reading

Comment: "csv" is a file format, not an application. The phrase "csv can load upto 1M" suggests that a specific application or programming environment is being used, but it's not clear which. Clarifying this would help others answer the question.

Comment: Can you use Python? (required by the first url given above)  or some other language? As the question stands right now there just is not enough information available.