# Filtering duplicate records in a CSV while loading it in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have duplicate records in a CSV file. Currently, I load it in a DataFrame and then drop the duplicates.

Is there a way to filter duplicates while reading CSV files?

Comment: If you read a CSV row by row you could skip those that are duplicates. However, reading a CSV with `pd.read_csv(...)` and dropping duplicates afterward will be faster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read large csv file with many duplicate values, drop duplicates while reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849793/read-large-csv-file-with-many-duplicate-values-drop-duplicates-while-reading)